# How can i set protocol model to multiple known types String / Object?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, realm, swift-protocols

API JSON Response
1st scene resp:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "code": 200,
    "response": {
        "error_message": "Incorrect email or password."
    }
}
```

2nd scene resp:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "code": 200,
    "response": {
        "error_message": {
            "email": [
                "Email is empty."
            ],
            "password": [
                "Password is empty."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My Protocol Model for response

```
protocol UserLoginResponse {
    var id : Int { get }
    var success: Bool { get }
    var code: Int { get }
    var response: UserLoginEntity? { get }
}
```

My problem is in the protocol below, don't know how to setup multiple types for error_message :

```
protocol UserLoginEntity {
    var error_message: String? { get }
}
```

Comment: Are you really stuck with web service design or are you open to changing it? You can write a custom `init(from:)` to deal with this, but it seems better to fix this web service design than program around it.

Comment: can u help me with the use of init(from: ) for the example post?

Comment: will it work if you change it from `var error_message: String? { get }` to `var error_message: Any? { get }` ?

Comment: I originally thought your question was about decoding JSON, but I now notice that you're just asking about protocols and tagged this as `realm` and don't actually ask about parsing. If you're just trying to figure out how to define a protocol for which the `response` object could be a different type, use [associated types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189). Rereading your question, I'm not at all clear what the root question really is.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use "Tuple" as error_message type will solve your problem:

```
typealias errorMsgType = (String,String)
var error_message: errorMsgType?

error_message = ("Email is empty.","Password is empty.")
print(error_message!)
print(error_message!.0)
print(error_message!.1)
```

another solution is little trick :

create a one string like:

```
let error1 = "Email is empty."
let error2 = "Password is empty."
let finalError = [error1,error2].joined(separator: "@@@@@@")
print(finalError)

let getErrors = finalError.components(separatedBy: "@@@@@@");
print(getErrors)
```